HTML/CSS toggle button read/write state
Looking for a way to have a page with toggle buttons on/off. i'm making a page that will be for me to track when my dogs were/need medication. (have a magnetic whiteboard now, but trying to go with digital dashboards throughout the house.) So I created a page with toggles using html and css, very basic. problem is, if I refresh the page, or pull up the page from a different dashboard they all revert to default of off. I tried searching but everything I could find was on how to create them. I need a way to write each button state to a file so it doesn't change on refresh.
Is this possible? maybe with javascript? asp? (never really done more than basic html/css stuff.)
Thanks
haven't tried that much, except for creating a page with buttons and finding out it doesn't write state anywhere. which after thinking about it was a DUH moment, because there is no output to anything. Then I tried to search, but probably didn't use the correct verbage.

You can do that using Web Storage API (localStorage, sessionStorage) saving the button  status. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

That would work for one computer, but what if OP wants to use multiple devices throughout their home?

Yes I run the dashboards from one server, but on multiple devices. I can store it one the dashboard server or a webserver.
